# Proving $x_n\leqslant C^n-x_1, \forall n\in\Bbb N,$ where $\{x_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}\subset\Bbb R^+, C\in(0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, proof-writing, induction

So far, for my proof I have:

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence of positive real numbers with the the property that $x_n+1/x_n < C\forall n\in\Bbb N$, where $0 < C < 1$.

**(a)** I know that I can prove this by induction.
Since for the basis step I would get $x_n\leqslant C\forall n\in\Bbb N$.
The inductive step is a bit tricky for me.

**(b)** Use the $e- K$ definition, and the result that $(x_n)$ converges to $0$. 
  b) since I am stuck in part a I’m not sure what result to use to prove that the sequence converges to $0$, but I do know that I can take the $\ln$ of both sides when solving and then this may be useful for part a which would let me say in part **(b)** something about $x<1$ then $\ln(x)<0$.